# How can I connect to a locally hosted site within a docker container?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect to a docker container's locally hosted address. I'm using Django to serve a website within the container, and I want to connect to it on my local machine. [image: this is the info i get from django from within the container.]

How can I access this site from my local machine?

I've tried to inspect the container and found that the local IP address is `172.28.0.4`. Even after specifying the correct port on my browser, it still won't connect.[image: this is what i see.]

The port 8000 is exposed in the container already, and added to the list of ports in the compose file.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you add the -p 8000:8000 argument?

Comment: Your question would be easier to read if you included the application output as plain text and not an image.  It looks like it says `Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000`, and if it says that, it won't be reachable from outside its own container; see for example ["The connection was reset" in localhost:8000 using django and docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60183313/the-connection-was-reset-in-localhost8000-using-django-and-docker).

Comment: @lucutzu33 I'm using docker compose https://imgur.com/a/guxU2PF

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send HTTP requests to my server running in a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338538/how-to-send-http-requests-to-my-server-running-in-a-docker-container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can connect to the docker instance through ssh, try:

`ssh user@172.28.0.4 -L 8000:172.28.0.4:8000`

Then navigate to your project and do `py manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Then on your local machine go to your browser and you should be able to access your app @ `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The server ip is managed by Django, and is locally hosted on 127.0.0.1:8000 which resolves to localhost. `python manage.py runserver` runs the server.

Comment: It appears that all that had to be done is specify the `0.0.0.0:8000` in the `runserver` argument.

Comment: You can't usually connect to a Docker container through ssh; they rarely run ssh daemons and these are very difficult to configure securely.